# Date: Text to Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As previously explained by one member of the community, I converted a text date format into a date format using "Text to columns"

Select column of dates then Data > text to columns > Next > Next > "under column data format" select "Date" and the format from dropdown (MDY or DMY) > OK
[image: Example]

However, as you can see on the screenshot, some dates do not convert. I tried various things but do not find a reason. If anyone could help, it would be greatly helpful

Comment: Even if text all dates must be at least in same MDY or DMY format. A mix of those cannot be transformed. Example: If 9/7/2016, 12/1/2016, 9/23/2016, 9/29/2016 are all MDY they will be successfully converted using MDY. But using DMY only 9/7/2016, 12/1/2016 can be converted, 9/23/2016, 9/29/2016 can not since there is not a month 23 or 29.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to replicate this seems to be formatting the cells appearance to dd.mm.yy. The fix being to change the cell format (visual mask) back to a standard date format. Text to columns does change the underlying data successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Initially, my dates (text format) were MDY but I used DMY (in text to column)and it only worked for 60% of the dates. Then I used MDY (in text to column) and it works for 100% of the dates converted.